# UITableview scroll freezes and becomes slow with usage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

It's been bugging me for days. I'm making a UITableview with fixed cell heights. Each cell has an image which has a tap gesture recognizer. When the app launches, the scrolling of the tableview is very smooth. But after scrolling many times, the tableview wouldn't scroll via the images. It scrolls perfectly if the images are not touched. It's like images become less sensitive to scroll swipe. Please note that i'm not loading the image in cell for row at index path but i'm adding a gesture recognizer in this method. I think that might be the problem but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you could show some of your code so it's easier to spot the issue.

Comment: From your statement: "When the app launches, the scrolling of the tableview is very smooth. But after scrolling many times, the tableview wouldn't scroll via the images. It scrolls perfectly if the images are not touched." i can say that your cell are not getting used. So every time when a cell is created it will occupy a memory for image this is leading your app to lag.

Comment: Even if the images are touched they scroll perfectly. But after many scrolling, if you swipe the tableview down or up from the image itself it becomes choppy and laggy.

Comment: Please share your code, especially the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and where you add the image and gesture. Are you dequeueing the cells?

Comment: The code is too long to be shared and yes i'm using dequeueing my cells. When i remove the gesture recognizers, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Have you thought about using just one gesture recognizer for the whole table and instead working out which image was tapped from recognizer.locationInView when the action is triggered? In my experience it works a lot better.

Comment: I fixed it thanks!

Comment: Please share your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was from the gesture recognizer as i said. I just replaced it with a button with the same size of the pic. It's on the pic with alpha = 0. Whenever i need the tap recognition, i just activate the alpha of the button which already has an IBAction. Hope this helps...